# Dispatch C function pointer with Swift type system

Tags: swift

I'd like to dispatch C function pointer with Swift type in my framework.
The C function will be provided in future by the framework user.

I think Protocol system is a way to realize that in that case.
How should I write?

The functions will be defined in C.

```c
void someIntFunction(int32_t*const x, int32_t count);
void someFloatFunction(float32_t*const x, int32_t count);
```

Suppose that the import of C functions is done without any problems.

The goal is dispatch these c functions depending on the type.
I try with Swift protocol system.

```swift
public protocol CFunctionPointerProvider {
  static var someFunctionPointer: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Self>, Int32) -> Void { get }
}
extension Int32 : CFunctionPointerProvider {
  public static var someFunctionPointer: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Self>, Int32) -> Void { someIntFunction } // imported from C
}
extension Float32 : CFunctionPointerProvider {
  public static var someFunctionPointer: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Self>, Int32) -> Void { someFloatFunction } // imported from C
}
public func applyTwice<T: CFunctionPointerProvider>(source: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, count: Int) {
    T.someFunctionPointer(source, Int32(count))
    T.someFunctionPointer(source, Int32(count))
}
```

These extensions will be defined by the framework user.
But I expect a work as

```
var intArray: [Int32] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
var floatArray: [Float32] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
applyTwice(source: &intArray, count: intArray.count) // call user-defined someIntFunction
applyTwice(source: &floatArray, count: floatArray.count) // call user-defined someFloatFunction
```

However, the above code cannot be built with the error '(UnsafeMutablePointer, Int32) -> Void' is not representable in Objective-C, so it cannot be used with '@convention(c)'.
I think the protocol-self should have a constraint which can be applied to ONLY C-compatible value types to realize the above code.
How should I write the constraint?

Also, is there any other way to dispatch C function pointers at compile time with type system.

Comment: You don't actually need the `@convention(c)`, do you? The functions you are calling are C functions already, so will use the C convention anyway.

Comment: Almost yes. It can be built without `@convention(c)`. `@convention(c)` or `@convention(thin)` are however required in my purpose. By using `@convention(swift)`, `@convention(block)`, the C function pointer has implicitly wrapped up in, that will lose a compatible with raw C and the raw address has been changed. The `@convention(thin)` sometimes makes swift compiler crashed although that is better than other `@convention` keywords.

Comment: I'd love to try to help here, but I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate more on it?